# Looking for a novel about a painting that is a portal to a land with faries,

Tags: story-identification, elves

Novel has a painting that is a portal to another land with faries, main character is a wizard's daughter. Book is written by a woman.  Story has an avoidance spell, an imprisoned queen farie, main character is a girl, surrounded by butterflies who is a wizard's daughter

Comment: Approximately when did you read it? Was it in English? Paperback or hardback? Do you remember anything about the cover?

Comment: Inkheart by Cornelia Funke?